# ZF2 - pass variables to zend build-in helper

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I would like to pass variable (that would be service menager) to a build-in helper of zend. Is it possible? To be more clearly:

1. There is a zend helper called Url, which constructs url's
2. In this helper I would like to get some data from database, so I need to pass there connection or model (doesn't matter really)
3. Depends on data get in point 2. I would like to construct my custom link

Well, the thing looks like this: I'm trying to make own custom routing. So in database I have controller, action and it's alias. For example:

```
 Home\Controller\Home | index | myalias
```

Routing works fine, that means that if I type url:

```
 example.com/myalias
```

Then Zend will open Home controller and index action. But on whole page I have url's made by Zend build-in Url helper, which looks like this:

```
$this->url('home', array('action' => 'index'));
```

So link looks:

```
example.com/home/index
```

I would like to change link to

```
example.com/myalias
```

without changing links generated by Url helper on whole page. So before helper return url, should check if that url have alias, and if so then should return that alias exept regular url.

Comment: Do you mean something like this answer -> http://stackoverflow.com/a/22624829/1112089

Comment: Are you talking about the url view-helper or the url controller plugin?

Comment: @Ruben About view-helper.

Answer (score 0):

In Module.php of the module where you have he helper class file, write the following -

```
//use statements

class Module {
    //public function getAutoloaderConfig() { [...] }

    //public function getConfig() { [...] }

    public function getViewHelperConfig() {
        return array(
            'factories' => array(
                'Url' => function ($sm) {
                    $locator = $sm->getServiceLocator();
                    $viewHelper = new View\Helper\Url;

                    //passing ServiceLocator to Url.php
                    $viewHelper->setServiceLocator($locator);  //service locator is passed.

                    return $viewHelper;
                },
            ),
        );
    }
}
```

Now in the Url.php, we need a function `setServiceLocator()` and `getServiceLocator()`.

```
//use statements

class Url {

    public $serviceLocator;

    public function getServiceLocator() {
        return $this->serviceLocator;
    }

    public function setServiceLocator($serviceLocator) {
        if($this->serviceLocator == null)
            $this->serviceLocator = $serviceLocator;

        return;
    }

}
```

I hope it helps.